# Setting a section in Libre Office to the top of a (new) page

Tags: libreoffice-writer

When one inserts a new section in LibreOffice it starts mid-page. This is the expected behaviour. However I do not know of a way to start a new page with a section. If one forces a page break the section starts one line down as the section is now after the empty line. This often means that I have sections that overflow a page by a line or two which looks messy.

How do I force a section to start at the VERY top of a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow these steps:

1. Put cursor into heading;
2. Select Menu `Format` -> `Paragraph`;
3. Select `Text flow` tab;
4. Under `Breaks`, tick `insert` (type `page` and position `default` should be set as default):
   [image]
5. That's it - click OK. This won't change the behaviour of every heading, but just the current heading.

Comment: You can insert a page or column break this way, not a section.