# Merge two ODT-files with the same style names

Tags: merge, libreoffice-writer, styles

I have two text documents with formatted text. I want to merge these: I need to insert document B into document A as a chapter.

Unfortunately they define the same styles.

Before:

Document A:

[image: Document A]

Document B:

[image: Document B]

Wanted result:

[image: Document A with B inside - wanted result]

If I simply paste B into A the style is not kept (it uses the Heading 1 and Text body styles from A), and it affects the chapter count.

[image: Document A with B inside - actual result]

In this example it is shown on the same page, but B is full pages, so it is fine, if I need to insert a new page before and after B.

Is there a way I can rename styles in document B, so they can be copied to document A without conflicting? It seems renaming a default style is grayed out:

[image: renaming style]

Or apply the styles as custom styling of each paragraph? Or copy the default styles, rename the copies, and some how replace all the old styles with new styles?

Answer (score 1):

Try marking a [*Section Break*](https://superuser.com/questions/966948/setting-a-section-in-libre-office-to-the-top-of-a-new-page) , put in a carriage return (<kbd>Enter</kbd>), add another *Section Break*. and then *paste the chapter between the two breaks*.

That should preserve standard formatting before and after, while allowing the chapter to preserve *its* formatting.

Comment: I still got the result as shown in the question.